# EF and existing database and table, with a bunch of new tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework

EF and existing database and table, with a bunch of new tables.

#### Context:

An old database has a Table User that the new application will use.
I used the entity `DataModel` Wizard to Map it [this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-from-existing-database.aspx) .

#### What I have now :

A bunch of new entities  and their configuration:

```
public class Bundle
{
    public Bundle() { Produits = new HashSet<Produit>(); }
    public int BundleID { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Produit> Produits { get; set; }
}

public class BundleConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Bundle>
{
    public BundleConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("PL_Bundle");
        HasKey(e => e.BundleID);
        Property(e => e.Designation).HasMaxLength(200);
    }
}
```

A `DbContext` with an extension using reflection to map all available configuration.

```
public partial class FooBarDbContext : DbContext
{
    public FooBarDbContext() : base("name=Model1")
       => Database.SetInitializer<FooBarDbContext>(null);
       
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyAllConfigurations();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
    
    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Bundle> Bundles { get; set; }
    // [...]
}

public static class ModelBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void ApplyAllConfigurations(this DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       IEnumerable<Type> typesToRegister
            = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                .SelectMany(t => t.GetTypes())
                .Where(t => t.IsClass)
                .Where(type => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(type.Namespace) &&
                        type.GetTypeInfo().BaseType != null &&
                        type.GetTypeInfo().BaseType.GetTypeInfo().IsGenericType &&
                        type.GetTypeInfo().BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(EntityTypeConfiguration<>))
                .ToArray();
        
        foreach (var type in typesToRegister)
        {
            dynamic configurationInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(configurationInstance);
        }
    }
}
```

In the calling application I am trying to test the Database and table to check  everything works..

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var db = new FooBarCore.DbContext.FooBarDbContext();
    
    var all = db.User.ToList();        // Work
    var bundles1 = db.Bundles.ToList();
```

The previous line give me error either :

> Nom d'objet 'dbo.PL_Bundle' non valide. => Invalid object name 'dbo.PL_Bundle'

#### What I tried:

1. Finding if `ModelBuilderExtensions` was an issue. But using classical `modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BundleConfiguration());`.
   Or using fluent API directly in the `OnModelCreating` throw the same error.
2. Check the database => Table are not here.
3. Search for `EF not create table`, but `CreateDatabaseIfNotExist`, `DropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges`, `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` are scary, they all have this Drop Database in the name.

Comment: so basically your DB and your model are out of sync. Have created a migration? Have you run `Update-Database`? It is in general bad idea to apply migrations in code. It's much better to generate scripts and have human apply them - he will know it's serious, make backup etc.

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek, I'm a simple man I read documentation from top to bottom and this entry was at the end : [Code-Based Migration](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-based-migration-in-code-first.aspx) .
Using the right key word I was able to find the solution. Yes I had a sync issue. I run: Enable-Migrations, Add-Migration, Update-Databas. But I manualy Edit the migration to not drop or recreate the Exisiting table User! Do you think this clarification is worth your time and an answer?

Answer (score 1):

so, as stated in comment:

> Nom d'objet 'dbo.PL_Bundle' non valide. => Invalid object name
>   'dbo.PL_Bundle'

this means, that EF thinks that there should be a table PL_Bundle, but there isn't. It isn't there, because you added new class into your model.

For EF to make proper change to the database, you should mechanism called [Migrations](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-based-migration-in-code-first.aspx)

You have to enable migrations, generate migration and apply it to the database.

Good practice is to store the migrations also as SQL scripts (by using UpdateDatabase -script) and make system admin apply them manually to prevent any secret datalosses if you remove a column or a table for example.

You ship the scripts with new versions of software and it should crash until the migration is applied, stating in logs which one is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Update your DbContext class to this:

```
public partial class FooBarDbContext : DbContext
{
    public FooBarDbContext() : base("name=Model1")
       => Database.SetInitializer<FooBarDbContext>(null);

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       //Configurations for Bundle class
       modelBuilder.Entity<Bundle>()
                .ToTable("PL_Bundle")
        .HasKey(e => e.BundleID);
        .Property(e => e.Designation).HasMaxLength(200);

        modelBuilder.ApplyAllConfigurations();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Bundle> Bundles { get; set; }
    // [...]
}
```

Comment: As stated: The add part is in the  `modelBuilder.ApplyAllConfigurations();` the fluent is in a `EntityTypeConfiguration` and thats the First things that I tried, Using both `modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BundleConfiguration());` and like you fluent api directly. The issue seems to lbe more on the initializer part. but I had to be complete in my question

Comment: `Database.SetInitializer<FooBarDbContext>(null);` means Don't create table but other choice are either drop database or drop database. and i want neither of those .